# Get Moonlight working with Firefox

Tags: firefox, moonlight

[County of San Diego - Planning and Development Services - Zoning And Property Information Tool](https://gis-public.co.san-diego.ca.us/COSDMAPS/Viewer.html?Viewer=Property%20Profile%20Map) displays:

[image: Silverlight]

which leads to a [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/) page:

> Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework
>   based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime.

with a bunch of `mono` stuff getting installed for Linux. [Mono Basics](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/):

> After you get Mono installed, it’s probably a good idea to run a quick Hello World
>   program to make sure everything is set up properly.

Testing:

```
$ cat >hello.cs
using System;
 public class HelloWorld
{
  static public void Main ()
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
  }
}
$ mcs hello.cs
$ mono hello.exe
Hello Mono World
```

Restarting Firefox leads to the same place. How does one get the map viewer to work?

This question has been rejected by the Web Application exchange as not being a question about a web app.

Comment: I recall that Silverlight just don't work in linux.

Comment: Tell them to publish their public information in an accessible format...